# Android XML Preview error using .arr

Tags: android, xml, arr

here's my problem: I wrote a framework in an `android` project including some basic methods and some resource(something like colors and themes). I compile it to arr and make the depandenciy to the arr. All things works well except rendering problems in xml preview.

The error message is like: 
Couldn't resolve resource `@color/color`)navigationbarcolor (21 similar errors not shown)
Theme attribut @android:navigationBarColor does not reference a color, instead is `color/color_navigationbarcolor`.(11 similar errors not shown).

anyone has any idea to solve this problem? Thanks a lot~~

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdHAa.png)

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I wrote the framework in MyLibs and the build.gradle in app is like compile project(':MyLibs:base-framework').  Then I complie and put "base-framework.arr" in app/libs and change dependencies like complie(name: 'base-framework', ext: 'arr'). Project can run, but when edit xml, i cannot see preview.

Comment: Please include the snapshot of the error @Softcloud

Comment: [the error snapshot is here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sdHAa.png)